# Unable to publish to Http Remote Repository

Tags: iis-7, openwrap

I think this might be an IIS7 permissions thing, but I'm tagging it with OpenWrap because I might be wrong. When I try to publish a wrap to an HTTP repository I get the following error:

```
PS C:\OpenWrapExamples\Ninject> o publish-wrap -Name Ninject -remote MyHttpRepo
# OpenWrap Shell 2.0.0.10
# Copyright © naughtyProd Limited 2009-2011
# Using C:\OpenWrapExamples\Ninject\wraps\_cache\openwrap-1.0.1.81349963\bin-net35\OpenWrap.dll (1.0.0.0)

Publishing package 'Ninject-2.2.0.85378492.wrap' to 'MyHttpRepo'
The repository OpenWrap.Repositories.Http.HttpRepositoryNavigator is read-only.
```

I've tried setting the permissions on the folder, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just exposed an indexed-folder (one you added with file:///path/) as an IIS site, it will be read-only (as there's little we can do with that).

If you use OpenWrap 1.0, , you can simply add two remotes, one for the UNC path (so you can publish) and the other one for the http one (so you can read the content back).

If you use the upcoming OpenWrap 2.0.1, you can simply add both in one go
    o add-remote http://server/ -publish file://server/path/to/share

If you want a repository writeable over HTTP, you can implement that feature yourself rather easily: have your index file at /index.wraplist, add an endpoint that support a POST with some content (that's the package), say at /upload, and add the following to your index.wraplist:

OpenWrap will then happily upload to an http endpoint.